# Summing a range of numbers after checking that is greater than a year

Tags: excel, excel-formula, excel-2016

currently i'm creating a outstanding payment list on excel that helps to consolidate figures and numbers that are overdue more than a year (Cell C44).

[image: Image here]

The issue with the image is that, the invoice #55 dated amounting to $55 on 12.12.17 is not yet a year outstanding but it appeared in Cell C44.

I format my date columns in dd.mm.yy as Text. So how I do i code it in such a way that, it checks all the date (Column B) and sums it into Cell C44 ONLY if it the date is outstanding greater than a year?

Here is the code sample.

`=SUMIF(B24:B29,"<31.12.16",E24:E29)-SUMIF(B24:B29,"<31.12.16",G24:G29)`

Any help would be appreciated.

UPDATE AS AT 06/01/2018

I tried integrating the MID formula into the code like this `=SUMIF(B24:B29,MID(B24:B29,7,2)<="16",E24:E29)-SUMIF(B24:B29,MID(B24:B29,7,2)<="16",G24:G29)`

[image: Image 2]
But it returned 0. What can i do?

Comment: I strongly suggest not storing your dates as text. That makes formulas more difficult.

Comment: Noted, but it's my company's standard since last time that they stored dates using texts.. I was told not to change if possible. Oh well..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As your dates are always dd.mm.yy you can use the `DATE()` function to build a date from parts:

`=DATE("20"&RIGHT(B24:B29,2),MID(B24:B29,4,2),LEFT(B24:B29,2))` - All formulas in this answer are array formulas; <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>Enter</kbd> While still in the formula bar

That will build an array of the dates.

Using this you can do a logical operation on the date value:

`=IF(DATE("20"&RIGHT(B24:B29,2),MID(B24:B29,4,2),LEFT(B24:B29,2))<DATE(2016,12,31),E24:E29-G24:G29)`

Doing this we have now built an array of the values in `E` minus the values in `G`, so all that is left is to sum it:

`=SUM(IF(DATE("20"&RIGHT(B24:B29,2),MID(B24:B29,4,2),LEFT(B24:B29,2))<DATE(2016,12,31),E24:E29-G24:G29))`

**EDIT:**

`=SUM(IF(IFERROR(DATE("20"&RIGHT(B24:B29,2),MID(B24:B29,4,2),LEFT(B24:B29,2))<DATE(2016,12,31),0),E24:E29-G24:G29,0))`

To produce `0` values for avoiding errors.

Comment: tried putting in your code, it returned the #VALUE.

Comment: @MelvinGoh Sorry the DATE() part returns #VALUE when the date cannot be formed, I have wrapped this in an `IFERROR` to produce 0 instead, please see edit

Comment: hmm, still returns zero. I tried changing the date to 12.12.14 and it still didnt update to the correct figure. Thanks for trying though.

Comment: @MelvinGoh The logical operator is hard coded in my answer here: `<DATE(2016,12,31)` this is the part that is being assessed against. Did you do the Ctrl+Shift+Enter? Should be working I'll have a look tomorrow when I'm back at my computer

Comment: Oh wow, thanks Richard! It worked. I didnt hit the Ctrl+Shift+Enter. Now i did so and it worked. Whats the difference between just hitting "enter" alone and "Ctrl+Shift+Enter" anyway? I dont quite get the difference.

Comment: @MelvinGoh Ah good news then! Glad to help out. The difference is that Ctrl+Shift+Enter confirms an Array formula, this treats ranges as an array object so the IF statements returns something like this `{1;0;1;0;0}` that we can then treat as a range rather than returning just a single 1 or 0. We essentially force it to evaluate each row separately and array the results. It saves you from needing to break the formula up into helper columns. (I'm not the best at describing it you might make more sense of it from a few searches)